# Launch a job using Ansible Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm trying to launch a new jobs using job templates in my ansible tasks.

Here's the example:

```
---
- name: default_process_backup
  hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - name: Launch Backup Fetch Files Job
      tower_job_launch:
        job_template: "backup_fetch_files"
    - name: Launch Backup Fetch MariaDB Job
      tower_job_launch:
        job_template: "backup_fetch_mariadb"
    - name: Launch Backup Fetch Postgres Job
      tower_job_launch:
        job_template: "backup_fetch_postgres"
```

While running a job with that tasks in Ansible Tower, i get next error:

> ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled
>   module name, or incorrect module path.

According to docs (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/tower_job_launch_module.html#requirements-on-host-that-executes-module) im doing right. What could be the issue and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`tower_job_launch` is supported in Ansible 2.3 and later.

I guess, you should upgrade Ansible version...